# Is there a name for defining a variables type with a list of values instead of a type?

Tags: typescript

I've found some code that defines a class with the following variables like so.

```
export class Foo {
  id: string = "A regular string"
  bar: '>' | '<' | '=' | '<=' | '>=' = '>';
}
```

What confuses me is the variable 'bar'. Rather than having a type definition, in it's place there seems to be a list of strings separated by pipes with an assignment to one of these strings at the end.

Intuition tells me that this dictates that the variable bar is limited to the listed values and is eventually assigned the value '>'.

Is there a name for this? I can't find it anywhere in the docs on variable declaration.

Comment: That would be named a `type`. You could also do `type Symbols = '>' | '<' | '=' | '<=' | '>='` and then `bar: Symbols`.

Comment: [Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). In this case, it's a union of literal string types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at there is a `union type`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

`bar` can only equal one of the values specified after the `:` (`>` or `<` or `=` or `<=` or `>=`)

The last `=` (after the union type) specifies the default value for `bar` which, as you noted, is `>`.

Hope this helped, check the link I posted for more information about union types.

Comment: Great, thanks. Found it in there under 'string literal types'.